# Errors when building QMYSQL plugin for qt-Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, qt, window

I am building the Qmysql plugin for qt and i am getting a error when I run a  qmake command. When i run this command `qmake -o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Progra~1/MySQL/MySQLS~1.0/include" "LIBS+=C:/Progra~1/MySQL/MySQLS~1.0/lib/opt/liblibmysql.a" mysql.pro` I get an error saying `Cannot find file: mysql.pro` . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your source tree, ensure there is `mysql.pro` in dir `%QTDIR%/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql`.

cd to `%QTDIR%/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql`, then retry.

Comment: There isn’t, how do I download it?